# How can I use variables when running an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to put together the following query:

```
new_fid_num =  select max(fid)+1 from field;

insert into field values(new_fid_num, 'StartDate', 8, 'The first date that data is available on BMLL', 'T', 'T');
```

I am not quite sure how to translate it into SQL, I tried something using `DECLARE` but that doesn't work. Any ideas how I can achieve the above?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? `DECLARE` is how you declare a variable in SQL. `DECLARE @new_fid_num INT = select max(fid)+1 from table;`. Also, keep in mind that this selection can cause duplicates if two queries run in parallel. The correct way to do it is using the built-in auto increment. Or locking the table if that is not available somehow.

Comment: You can simply do `INSERT INTO dtab SELECT max... `, However, use auto-increment or similar (depending on dbms), as Ortiga suggested.

Comment: When I run the above, I get: 

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 1: DECLARE @new_fid_num INT = select max(fid)+1 from table;`

Comment: @ifrj, that's because you aren't using the same dbms... I assume you now understand the importance of adding a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Noooooo. Don't do `max+1` to set new ID values. It leads to race conditions and performance issues. Your database has a built-in mechanism for this... probably more than one. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use your select statement AS the value such as

```
insert into field
( explicitColumnName1,
  explicitColumnName2,
  explicitColumnName3,
  explicitColumnName4,
  explicitColumnName5,
  explicitColumnName6 
)
values
( 
  ( select max(fid)+1 from field ),
  'StartDate', 
  8, 
  'The first date that data is available on BMLL', 
  'T', 
  'T'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @new_fid_num int;

SET @new_fid_num =  (select max(fid)+1 from field);

insert into field (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) values(@new_fid_num, 'StartDate', 8, 'The first date that data is available on BMLL', 'T', 'T');
```

I guess you need to put SELECT query inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified - at least tell us/OP which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh this is for MSSQL.